# TCP sockets returning strange thing in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have socket application that i use for communication with a device.

When i open socket i can read status outputs from the machine.
Machine sends some data which is separated by comma ',' and i need to parse only numbers.

The problem is when i parse the data i recieve numbers but i also recieve "empty" strings.

Here is my code:

```
void startListenForTCP(String ipaddress) {

  Thread TCPListenerThread;
  TCPListenerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      Boolean run = true;
      String serverMessage = null;
      InetAddress serverAddr = null;
      BufferedWriter out = null;
      int redni = 0;
      try {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(ipaddress, 7420);

        try {
          mc.pushNumbers("Connection initiated... waiting for outputs!"
              + "\n");
          char[] buffer = new char[2];
          int charsRead = 0;
          out =
              new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                  clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
          BufferedReader in =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  clientSocket.getInputStream()));
          while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {

            String message = new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
            if (message.equals("I,")) {
              mc.pushNumbers("\n");
            } else {
              String m = message;
              m = m.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

              String stabilo = m;
              int length = stabilo.length();
              String result = "";
              for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Character character = stabilo.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
                  result += character;
                }
              }
              System.out.println("Result:" + m);
            }
          }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          mc.pushNumbers("Unknown host..." + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
          mc.pushNumbers("IO Error..." + "\n");
        } finally {
          clientSocket.close();
        }

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mc.pushNumbers("Connection refused by machine..." + "\n");
      }
    }

  });
  TCPListenerThread.start();
}
```

And the `System.out.println();` returns this:

```
Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:26Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:13
Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:Result:
```

I just don't know why I can't parse only numbers, there is probably something that machine sends and it isn't parsed by `m = m.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");`

Answer (score 0):

You're building your String incorrectly. It should be:

```
String message = new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

where 'bytesRead' is the count returned by the read() method. It's a byte count, not a char count.

Comment: And yeah, it is again returning empty strings.

Comment: So you're replacing all strings starting with a digit by nothing and you're surprised that the result is an empty string? Doesn't that suggest that the string originally started with a digit? and was completely replaced by nothing? by your code? and that this has nothing to do with TCP sockets?

Comment: Ok, thank you, that was the most helpful comment ever. I was just looking for someone to show me where did i go wrong. If you can show me what to change in my code that would be nice. If not thank you anyway.

Comment: Only you know what your code is suppose to do. You should start by receiving why you are doing this replace at all, and why if the result is empty you are then continuing to process an empty string. Only you can answer these questions. None of it makes sense to me.